# Issue with how to slide user control left/right

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I have a view and within the view, there are two user control, each with a button on it. When the page loads, the first user control will load. when i click on the button in the first user control, I would like to slide the first user control left, making it invisible and display the second user control. when i click on the button in the second user control, I would like to slide the second user control right, making it invisible and displaying the first user control again. can anyone help on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get correctly, you want something like Carousel in wpf. In case that's it, [here's](http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/) the link. It allows you to slide several items left-right to switch between them.

Another way to go would be using default animations in WPF, meaning DoubleAnimation applied to Margin property that increases margin from 0 to 500 (to move it off the screen) and back to 0 (to return it) or something like that. Head's up for double animation and moving controls is [here](http://pradeepmahdevu.blogspot.com/2009/02/flying-grids-using-margin-animation.html) and official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx).

Comment: When the page load, the first user control is loaded which has a button. When I click on the button, I want it to slide in the second user control. vice versa when the second user control is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hard-code an animation designed for your specific scenario, you could do something a little more generic and adapt the [TransitionControl](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/11/wpf-transitions-using-pixel-shaders-and.html) that uses pixel shaders.  Set the content property and you can specify which shader effect you want it to apply as the transition.